# ColorOrder setting has no effect

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I am using Matlab version R2014a and I am trying to have `plot` look like the Simulink scope. My code works as it should except, the `ColorOrder` setting is not reflected in the output.

Right after setting `ColorOrder` I retrieved it with `current_co=get(gca, 'ColorOrder');` and it gives back the value that I have set. However in the diagram the default colors are used.

Why is this? How can it be fixed?

```
my_co=[1.0 1.0 0.0; 1.0 0.0 1.0; 0.0 1.0 1.0; 1.0 0.0 0.0; 0.0 1.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0 1.0; 1.0 1.0 1.0];
figure('Color', [0.2 0.2 0.2]);
plot(ScopeData(:,2:6));
legend('w(t)','e(t)','y(t)','x(t)','z(t)');
set(gca, 'ColorOrder', my_co);
set(gca, 'Color', 'black');
set(gca, 'XColor', 'white');
set(gca, 'YColor', 'white');
set(gca, 'XGrid', 'on');
set(gca, 'YGrid', 'on');
title('My funky title!', 'Color', 'white');
xlabel('t/[s]');
```

Comment: What do you mean? I get a plot with colors that are definetly not the default. Black background, white axis. I get this: https://imgur.com/MO3V5jC but ther eis ane rror saving, so the white are is black and the axis can be seen

Comment: @AnderBiguri huh, I don't understand. Mine looks like this: [http://imgur.com/Yj2y3Qy](http://imgur.com/Yj2y3Qy). I might have to use `plot(x,y1,color1, x,y2,color2, ...)` which **does** honor the colors.

Comment: yes, it looks liek that. What is the problem then? you are aware that we dotn have your data, so we dont know if the order of the colors are rigth..............

Comment: @AnderBiguri Those are the default plot colors for 2014b+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the `ColorOrder` property *before* plotting anything. Plot objects respect the *current* value of the `ColorOrder` property when they are created and changing the `ColorOrder` *after* they are created only has an effect on future plots. **Also note that you need to call `hold on` prior to plotting anything to prevent the `axes` from going back to the default `ColorOrder`**.

```
my_co = [1 1 0; 1 0 1; 0 1 1; 1 0 0; 0 1 0; 0 0 1; 1 1 1];
figure('Color', [0.2 0.2 0.2]);

% Set this before plotting anything
set(gca, 'ColorOrder', my_co);
hold on

% NOW plot your data
plot(ScopeData(:,2:6));
legend('w(t)','e(t)','y(t)','x(t)','z(t)');
set(gca, 'ColorOrder', my_co);
set(gca, 'Color', 'black');
set(gca, 'XColor', 'white');
set(gca, 'YColor', 'white');
set(gca, 'XGrid', 'on');
set(gca, 'YGrid', 'on');
title('My funky title!', 'Color', 'white');
xlabel('t/[s]');

% If you want you can turn hold off now
hold off
```

This makes sense because if you create a plot using a custom color:

```
plot(data, 'Color', 'magenta')
```

You wouldn't want the axes automatically changing this manual color when the `ColorOrder` property is changed.

[image]